# Is it possible to create a UV map from a rendered object in Blender

Tags: 3d, blender-2.50, blender-2.61

I am wondering if it is possible, and if so, how, to create a UV map from a high detail rendered image in blender, sort of like you can do in professional 3D applications and game engines, like Maya, for instance.

I would like to be able to create some high detail renders and map them to a low poly mesh.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

I am willing to consider using a plugin or other 3rd party application to accomplish this task. I prefer free, though.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `Texture Baking` or `Render Baking`.  Below two links from Blender's website.

[Render Baking](http://www.blender.org/development/release-logs/blender-243/render-baking/):

> Blender's render pipeline supports rendering to UV texturemaps as
>   well. This is only supported for Mesh Objects with texture faces and
>   Images assigned.

[Baking Selected to Active](http://www.blender.org/development/release-logs/blender-246/render-baking/):

> A typical use case is to make a detailed, high poly object, and then
>   bake it's normals onto an object with a low polygon count. The
>   resulting normal map can then be applied to make the low poly object
>   look more detailed.